# Method other than polling to Download a file that may be being updated by server

Tags: java, download, polling, gzip

My code can download any file from a given url. The problem is that i have to download search results that are in .gz file format which is being continuously updated.

my code is downloading incomplete file as the server's search is going on.
I have already tried polling, ie i downloaded the file twice and matched the size etc etc.

Is there any other method that can be tried?

Comment: what's the purpose of polling? to check whether it's enf-of-file? to check the total file size?

Comment: I used polling to check the size of file

Comment: does the server update the file size in the Content-Length in the response headers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not properly process response headers - if server returns 'chunked' response, you should load it by parts.
To ensure it, user firefox/firebug and check response headers for test request.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Also check response for other headers like Content-Length/Keep-Alive.